# Microsoft Graph API outlook task folder : NoPermissionsInAccessToken

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to list the Outlook Task Folders using Microsoft Graph with POSTMan.
Following is the URL I am using:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/taskFolders
```

After adding the Bearer Token in the request header, I am getting the following response Graph:

```
"code": "NoPermissionsInAccessToken",
"message": "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.",
```

I have already enabled the following permissions:`Tasks.ReadWrite`. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you add how you are getting the access token?

Comment: This is url i am using for getting the token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token

And following are the parameters passing as part of the GET Request:
grant_type - client_credentials,
scope - https://graph.microsoft.com/.default,
client_id,client_secret

Comment: Can you clarify, did you mean `POST` instead of `GET` request (hint: it _should_ be a `POST` :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue while using `client credentials flow` to get access token. I [decode the access token](https://jwt.io/) and do not see the permission I assigned. As the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) said:

> The **permission is delegated from the user** to the application, usually during the consent process. However, in the **client credentials flow, permissions are granted directly to the application itself**. When the app presents a token to a resource, the resource enforces that the app itself has authorization to perform an action and not the user.

So, I suggest that you could use `OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow` to get the access token. And add your `Tasks.Read` permission in scope.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:123
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Tasks.Read
```

For more details to get access token with auth code flow you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

Comment: Can i use url "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:123
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Tasks.Read"
in Postman? Because i guess the above url takes us to login page, but i would need to access the TaskFolder graph api from application. Please let me know if my understanding is not correct.

Comment: You can use the url in browser and login your account. And after get access token, you could go to decoded it and you will find `Tasks.Read` permission in `scp ` property.

Comment: As the permission is delegated, so you need to use user to login.

Comment: Because when i am hitting the above url, it is taking me to the Sign Page which may not work for me, as i wanted it inside the c# code.

Comment: If so, I will suggest that you could use [OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow.